# Fast Stored Procedure but slow when executing using jobs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

I have a stored procedure which runs fast when executing it or highlighting the script an hitting f5 which usually runs or executes the code.

It only took a second or 1.5 seconds just to select top 3 from 1 table which is from one server and insert it to another table which is also in another server.

But when i tried to execute the stored procedure using jobs, it takes a lifetime just to do that. Am I missing something?

```
USE [xxxx]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MARK_ACTIVE]    Script Date: 4/20/2015 5:55:53 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxx]
AS
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
INSERT INTO [123.456.7.890].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE]    (smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX)
SELECT TOP 3 smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX
FROM [098.765.4.321].[[DBASE2].[dbo].[TABLE2] cr
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT  id,smsfr,smsmsg,smsdt,dbdt,devid,status,status2,IsHEX     FROM [123.456.7.890].[DBASE1].[dbo].[TABLE]  c
      WHERE cr.smsdt = c.smsdt)
```

Comment: Is the extra `[` in `FROM [098.765.4.321].[[DBASE2].[dbo].[TABLE2] cr` a typo?

Comment: yes it is just a typo error. Sorry

Comment: Is this running on a schedule? Have you tried manually setting the agent job going by right clicking on the job? It might be that if it is a scheduled job, it is running along with other jobs that are causing the I/O of either server to be increased. This would cause slow down.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the same stored proc called from any connection should run roughly the same speed, regardless of who called it. But... there are connection settings that will cause different execution plans to be created. If you're getting different performance between running things in SSMS (locally from your own PC presumably) and what is being run automatically on your server, I'd check the ANSI connection settings on both machines. See what's different, because I'll bet you've got something different there